# How can I set the horizontal separation only in a framebox?

Tags: boxes, framed

I'm using the command `\fcolorbox` to add a framebox around an image.
I want to set the horizontal separation only.
With `\fboxsep` I set the separation all around.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.75}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}

\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \fcolorbox{light-gray}{white}{\includegraphics[trim=0mm 2mm 0mm 2mm, clip=true, scale=1]{../figures/fig.pdf}}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I know, you can't :-(, at least not for `\fbox`. There are better packages, such as `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\FBox[3][1ex]{{% default space is 1ex
    \color{light-gray}\frame{\hspace{#1}\includegraphics[#2]{#3}\hspace{#1}}}}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.75}

\begin{document}
\frame{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{tiger}}% without space

\FBox[2em]{width=4cm}{tiger}% horizontal space is 2em

\FBox{width=4cm}{tiger}% now the default of 1ex     
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are using the `beamer` class then modify the command to:

```
\let\myFrame\frame
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\FBox[3][1ex]{{% default space is 1ex
        \color{light-gray}\myFrame{\hspace{#1}\includegraphics[#2]{#3}\hspace{#1}}}}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.75}
...
```

Comment: This won't work with `beamer`, of course. Besides, `\frame` is defined in the kernel, but it's not documented in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution, with a `myfcolorbox` comand which one optional argument, th horizontal distance between frame and contents:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.75}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \fcolorbox{light-gray}{white}{\hskip0.5em\includegraphics[trim=0mm 2mm 0mm 2mm, clip=true, scale=1]{../figures/fig.pdf}\hskip0.5em}
  \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following macro `\hfcolorbox` has the same syntax as `\fcolorbox`, but adds `\fboxsep` only at the left and right of the contents.

The setting of `\hfcolorboxsep` is set at the very last moment, so it will use the current value of `\fboxsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,xparse}

\newlength{\hfcolorboxsep}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hfcolorbox}{ommm}{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\hfcolorboxsep}{\fboxsep}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {\fcolorbox{#2}{#3}{\hspace{\hfcolorboxsep}#4\hspace{\hfcolorboxsep}}}%
   {\fcolorbox[#1]{#2}{#3}{\hspace{\hfcolorboxsep}#4\hspace{\hfcolorboxsep}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.75}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\hfcolorbox{light-gray}{white}{%
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]